# Purpose of checking @@rowcount = 0 in a trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I've read a book For eg., *Pro SQL Server 2008 Relation Database Design And Implementation Lois Davidson* where I've found suggestion to check the `@@rowcount` inside the trigger: `if it is = 0 then return`:

```
if @@rowcount = 0 return
```

I'm wondering if the no row is modified how come trigger is fired?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trigger fires for the *statement* being run. It will fire even if the table is empty, or if the statement affected no rows:

```
create table tr (i int);
go

create trigger g on tr after update
as 
print 'foo'
go


update tr set i = 2
```

@Muflix Update:

```
create table tr (i int);
go

create trigger g on tr after insert
as 
print 'foo'
go

insert into tr select * from tr;
go
```

As you see the trigger fires even if no rows were inserted.

Comment: it is important to check this in insert trigger too ?

Answer (score 2):

Becuase `Trigger` won't be able to know how many rows are affected by the triggering event that is why you have to check inside.

Comment: A trigger could do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [inserted]` though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

Trigger is fired because triggering event has occurred. Trigger does not
check how many rows are affected. Therefore you've to check `@@rowcount`
inside trigger body. To fire a trigger, triggering event is important and
not the number of rows affected.

Also be aware that the behaviour of `@@rowcount` in a trigger when fired by a MERGE statement in SQL Server 2008 is not what is expected and is different.